# Stop unwanted messages on website contact page (not spam)

Tags: php

Is there any method to stop unwanted (vulgar, distasteful and advertising not related to us) messages being sent to us from our website's contact page. We have a contact page on which users visiting our website may send us their genuine queries. But from the last two weeks we are getting unwanted type inquiries. Please note that they are not spam messages as they are not in bulk and we have CAPTCHA enabled on our website. But we get 20-30 such messages on daily basis and sometimes they are really vulgar and offensive. Before captcha such queries were in bulk but captcha has reduced them to 20-30 now. But they are still a lot in comparison to total inquiries we receive daily.

Is there any way to stop such messages being posted to us through code? The website is in PHP. Any other method apart from code will also be good.

I have asked this question here as I am asking from coding perspective to prevent such messages. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example image of the current CAPTCHA

Comment: try with this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-honeypot/

Comment: good luck preventing fµck, fu¢k, f.u.c.k, fuϲk, FUCᏦ and the endless permutations of it. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem. It's a [clbuttic](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=clbuttic) issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
    function detectBadWords($bad_words, $text) {
        foreach ($bad_words as $key => $word) {
            if (strpos($text, $word) != false) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    $text = 'bla bla bla';
    $bad_words = ['shit', 'fuck'];
    $check = detectBadWords($bad_words, $text);
    if ($check) {
        // prevent insert data
    }

 ?>
```

Comment: The OP knows that. The question is how.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the vulgar or offensive text to search and give the error when write that word.

```
function isAbusive(str) {
      var badWords = ['bad', 'worst','fuck','suck'];
      var isTrue = false;
      if(str) {
         for (var i = 0; i < badWords.length; i++) {
           isTrue = !!(str.replace(/\W|\s/g, '').toLowerCase().indexOf(badWords[i]) + 1);
           if(isTrue) break;
         }
      }
      return isTrue;
    }


var comments = document.getElementsByClassName("prevent_abuse");

for (var i = comments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  console.log(i, comments[i].innerHTML)
  if (isAbusive(comments[i].innerHTML)) {//you can check this comment
    alert("there is bad word");
    comments[i].parentNode.removeChild(comments[i]);
  }

}
```

This is the html code where the user comment or message.

```
<p class="prevent_abuse">I want to do "b/a/d" activity</p>
<p class="prevent_abuse">I want to do "worst" activity</p>
<p class="prevent_abuse">I want to do "good" activity</p>
<p class="prevent_abuse">bad activity</p>
<p class="prevent_abuse">W/O/R/s/T activity</p>
```